# eclipse: Not a valid location for linked resources

Tags: eclipse

I tried to link a project folder which is special vista folder appdata/roaming/user/myproj. It shows that error message above.

What prevents to do so ? I tried running as administrator but it gives the same message. Of course out of appdata folder it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perfectly can link appdata to an eclipse project folder.

But you need to enter its full absolute path:

```
 C:\users\UserName\AppData
```

(tested with eclipse3.5.1)