# Perl EPIC on Eclipse: "\Perl\Directory is not a valid location for linked resources"

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, epic

I am trying to debug a Perl script under EPIC on Eclipse (on Windows 7). When stepping along in the debugger, when it reaches the place where is has to jump to another package (called "Utilities.pm") due to a subroutine call, it gives the following succession of Eclipse errors:

```
'E:\Perl' is not a valid location for linked resources.
EPIC cannot access files located in folders on the path to the workspace folder, nor within the workspace folder itself.
An unexpected exception occurred while creating a link to E:/Perl/Utilities.pm
```

I am aware of this:
[eclipse: Not a valid location for linked resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655770/eclipse-not-a-valid-location-for-linked-resources) 
and this:
[Eclipse gives error "... is not a valid location for linked resources."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298029/eclipse-gives-error-is-not-a-valid-location-for-linked-resources)
But I can't deduce from them how to solve my case.

Running as Administrator doesn't help.

TIA

Helen

Eclipse version 3.7.1 build M20110909-1335, EPIC version 0.6.44, Active Perl 5.14.2 running on Windows 7.

Note: cross-posted on: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=972408

Comment: What's your workspace and project directory look like? I mean what's the path to them.

Comment: The Eclipse Workspace folder is: "E:\Perl\Eclipse workspace".    
The project folder is: "E:\Perl\Eclipse workspace\FBProject".    

But under "E:\Perl\Eclipse workspace\FBProject" I see another folder:
E:\Perl\Eclipse workspace\FBproject\Eclipse workspace.    

How do I make sure that the paths are set up right?

Comment: When I go, in the Eclipse menu: "FBProject -> Properties -> Linked Resources", it shows: PARENT_LOC:  "E:\Perl\Eclipse workspace";
PROJECT_LOC:   "E:\Perl\Eclipse workspace\FBProject";
WORKSPACE_LOC:  "E:\Perl\Eclipse workspace";

Perl include path: E:"\Perl"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was some inconsistency in the Workspace - Project -Linked Resources file structure. I have deleted the entire project, restarted from scratch, and then this error did not show up again.

But, the program hanged at another Eclispe/EPIC error, which I will post separately soon.

Here is the following problem:

[Perl debuuger: on a run-time error, the debugger terminates with a cryptic message instead of "catching" the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775274/perl-epic-on-eclipse-on-a-run-time-error-the-debugger-terminates-with-a-crypti)